# This question is for Unitarians/Biblical Unitarians as well and it is based on Acts 7:59-60

Tags: death, acts, stephen

Acts 7:59-60

> <sup>**59**</sup> And they went on stoning Stephen as he called upon the Lord and said, "Lord Jesus, receive my spirit! <sup>**60**</sup> And falling on his knees, he cried out with a loud voice, "Lord, do not hold this sin against them!" And having said this, he fell asleep.

Why did not Stephen call upon the "only true God?" It's interesting that Stephen's confession and Jesus' confession (Luke 23:34), there is a striking contrast; Jesus "commended" His spirit to the Father but Stephen, to the Lord Jesus Christ, why?

Comment: Is this question exclusively for Unitarians/Biblical Unitarians?  There are other anti-Trinitarian denominations that might have a reason for not praying to Christ Jesus to receive their spirit.

Comment: To be honest Lesley I'm pretty sure I was asked to "scope" the question to a specific group. If you notice the question says, "This question is for Unitarians/Biblical Unitarians AS WELL." If you want please edit the question in a way that conforms to other anti-Trinitarian denominations. I was surprised that there was no reply from Unitarians. Thank you!